# OEIS A000255 recursion.

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

I encountered the sequence [A000255](http://oeis.org/A000255). $a(n)$ counts permutations of $[1,...,n+1]$ having no substring $[k,k+1]$

I am finding difficulty in proving it.
Can you please give any clues or hints on how to attack the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recurrence is $a(n)=na(n-1)+(n-1)a(n-2)$  The first term is the number of ways to insert $n+1$ into a proper permutation of $[1,\ldots,n]$-you can put it anywhere except after $n$.  The second counts the ways to have a permutation of $[1,\ldots,n]$ with exactly one pair $[k,k+1]$, which you then break up by putting $n+1$ between them.  You choose which number will be $k$ (to be followed by $k+1$), but it can't be $n$.  Then link $k$ and $k+1$ as a pair and make a proper permutation (of $n-1$ items).

Comment: thanks , wonderful solution